# C# Get current latitude and longitude in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an application that will detect the user location show latitude and longitude and show the physical address against them. When I run this, I get nothing.

My system location is on and has an active internet connection. I see every time a dot in the task bar that someone is tracking location but I still get nothing.

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Device.Location;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace APIsProject
{
public partial class GetLatitudeandLongitude : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string latitude;
    private string longitute;
    private GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        // Catch the StatusChanged event.  
        watcher.StatusChanged += Watcher_StatusChanged;
        // Start the watcher.  
        watcher.Start();

    }

    private void Watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, 
    GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e) // Find GeoLocation of Device  
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
            {
                // Display the latitude and longitude.  
                if (watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
                {
                    latitude = "0";
                    longitute = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    latitude = 
       watcher.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString();
                    longitute = 
       watcher.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                latitude = "0";
                longitute = "0";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            latitude = "0";
            longitute = "0";
        }
    }

    protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         TextBoxLatitude.Text = latitude;
        TextBoxLongitude.Text = longitute;

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that in an ASP.NET application, you will always **track the location of your server**? If you want to track visitors positions, you need to use a client-side service.

Comment: Mean i have to use JavaScript embedded in page?

Comment: Yes. How else would it work?

Comment: @Filburt! but its not working at all. I tried it before posting question

Comment: Using the client side JS code in the answer below is the only way - you will of course need to add a function post back the values obtained from your visitor's browser. The C# code you tried is executed on your server and will - if any when deployed to your live web site - only return the location of the server (highly unlikely that a server has location services enabled and a builtin GPS module).

Answer (score 8):

You can try this to find position using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` :

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Live demo](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)

Comment: As an FYI, this only works if the site is running against HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Try This..It's Working...

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="location.WebForm2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>    
    <script>
        function getLocation()
        {
            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else
            {
                document.getElementById("Label1").value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }
        function showPosition(position)
        {
            document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = position.coords.latitude
            document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = position.coords.longitude;
        }
</script>
<%--<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>--%>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">     
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Button" OnClientClick="getLocation();return false;" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers are improved with some explanation

Comment: this is same as above answer and it will also work with https not working with http, however worked on localhost.